# Why orientating sprites doesn't work from ´didEndContact()´ but does from ´update()´

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsworld

I have the following code in my GameScene-class that orients all the moving sprites to the direction that they are going. It works perfectly if called from update() but I cannot understand why it doesn't work at all when called from didEndContact.

The problem with being called from update() is that when scene transition begins, update is no longer called (it seems) and all sprite stop orientating them selves. I have long scene transitions so it looks bad.

```
func updateSpriteDirections(){

    var i = 1
    var nodeToUpdate: SKSpriteNode?
    nodeToUpdate = self.childNodeWithName("sprite\(i)") as! SKSpriteNode!
    while (nodeToUpdate != nil){
        changeSpriteDirection(nodeToUpdate!)
        i += 1
        nodeToUpdate = self.childNodeWithName("sprite\(i)") as! SKSpriteNode!

    }


func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        updateSpriteDirections()
}
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    updateSpriteDirections()

}
func changeSpriteDirection(sprite: SKSpriteNode){

    let nodeToTurn = self.childNodeWithName(sprite.name!)
    if(nodeToTurn != nil) {
        let angle = atan2(sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dy, sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dx)
        nodeToTurn!.zRotation =  angle - 90 * DegreesToRadians
    }

}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but update: and didEndContact: are methods which are called automatically by system at very different moments. didEndContact is trigerred by the physics world and from its name you can eaisly conclude when and why it is called. update: method is called 60 times per second. So, comparing this two doesn't make sense.

Comment: To my understanding didEndContact is called after a physics contact happened, which would be perfect time to check if sprites need to be reorientated. Update is indeed called before each frame and therefore my sprites are being orientated unnecessarily often. To the death of me, I can't figure out why my code doesn't work from didEndContact. My best guess is that the sprite doesn't have new direction at the time of ´didEndContact´call so orientating sprite results still to the direction it was going before collition.

Comment: Actually, how do you move sprites ? Using actions, physics engine or do you manually change their position ? Also, is didEndContact executed at all ? Why don't you put a break point and see closely what is going on ? And one more question.. Does your sprites collide with other objects, or you just register contacts ?

Comment: Good questions! The sprites move by physics engine. I set them on the screen randomly, give a push a let them bounce around. I have set the physics so that they will bounce around infinitely. didEndContact is called. If i put print() there it comes out ok. The sprites collide to each other as well as screen edges.

Comment: Well, one way would be to store sprites in a temporary array, and to rotate them in didSimulatePhysics. After that you should remove them from the array. Still, you should be careful about all this becauase sprites can be pushed into collision after rotation and that can lead into unwanted behavior. So it can happen that some corrections may be needed. Another way, I am pretty much positive that could work is to reset sprite's rotation using SKAction. This would be similar e as you are doing right now, just effect will be postponed to the next frame (because of how SKAction work).

Comment: Still, you should keep in mind that any manual changing of position (or rotation) of a sprite that is involved in physics simulation can have unwanted results if not handled correctly. So for example, if you change those properties using SKAction, those effects will get into conflict with physics engine (because both effects are applied in a single frame), and you will have a mess. So, timing is important. Search SO about all this. In your case, everything will probably work because you just instantly change sprite's rotation...So I guess it will be fine.

Comment: I don't see the relevant difference between update() and didSimulatePhysics() in this case. Could you elaborate a bit on your idea for that? To my understanding both functions are called 60 times a second. I cannot use SKAction with these methods because to complete the SKAction takes more time than it takes to come back to update() on the rendering of next frame.

Comment: Additionally I've noticed that when I do self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: getTransition()) (I have 1,5 second long transition) from the scene where the sprites are bouncing, sprites keep on moving but updating their directions stops. This looks a bad on UI. I'm guessing that its related to something like once ´presentScene´ has been called rendering of previous scene stops but physics simulation still takes place. This is another reason that led me thinking that if I could implement orientation logic into ´didEndContact´ even the transition would look better.

Comment: Update is called before physics calculations. Take a peek about how SpriteKit renders frame. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks! What I meant though was that there isn't really significant difference for my case if I use update() or didSimulatePhysics().There could be if I could make this work from didEndContact().